# Querying DB2 view from Libreoffice Base

Tags: libreoffice, db2, libreoffice-base

I've created a view in DB2 that has the information I need for labels that I was hoping to print out from LibreOffice.  When I query the view from the console ("SELECT * FROM ADDRBOOK.LABELS"), I get a bunch of information, but if I try to view it from inside lobase, I get an error about cursors, [SQLSTATE 36001](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html#rsttmsg__code36).  I'm not sure what, if anything, I can do to get Base to play nice with DB2.

Note that I can open regular tables.  It must have something to do with the view.  (I already had trouble with the view, you can see it [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462150/sql-excluding-common-data).)  Any help would be appreciated!